# I cannot install PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying to make speech recognition software but it tells me that I need pyaudio. I have tried to install it using the wheel, and I have already tried `pip install PyAudio` and `brew portaudio` and `pipwin`, but nothing works, what can I do?

When I do this:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

It gives me this:
thank you for the help

```
WARNING: Requirement 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does 
not exist
Processing c:\users\berna\pyaudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\berna\\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl'
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you download the pyaudio wheel file to your file location?

Answer (score 0):

you can install py audio by just doing 3 steps
1.open the folder in command prompt in which your wheel file is there
2.copy and paste the pip file that you get with your python version
3.type in the command prompt pip install PyAudio

and enjoy